# How to initialize centroids in "k-means clustering" belonging to the domain of the data points?

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, k-means

How can I modify this code to initialize the centroids within the domain of the datapoints taken ?

For ex: if DATA = [[2.0, 5.0], [1.0, 5.0], [22.0, 55.0], [42.0, 12.0], [15.0, 16.0]]
Then centroids(x,y) could be any value such that x belong to :[1,42] and y belongs to : [5,55].
The centroids should not necessarily be datapoints.

Note: The dataype for data is float.

```
import random
import math

BIG_NUMBER = math.pow(10, 10)
data = []
centroids = []

class Centroid:
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def set_x(self, x):
    self.x = x

def get_x(self):
    return self.x

def set_y(self, y):
    self.y = y

def get_y(self):
    return self.y

def initialize_centroids(k,DATA):
for j in range(k):
    x = random.choice(DATA)
    centroids.append(Centroid(x[0], x[1]))

return
```

Comment: What is the problem with the example code? Is it that the centroids are not certainly unique?

Comment: @ James K - Initialized Centroids should not be exactly one of the data points, rather centroids(x,y) should be any value such that x belong to :[1,42] and y belongs to : [5,55] as it affects the performance of k means clustering.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way of initializing k-means uses randomly sampled data points.

Initialization by drawing random numbers from the data range does *not* improve results. This may seem like a good idea at first, but it is highly problematic, because it is built on the false assumption that the data is uniformly distributed. On the contrary, data is clustered, and the best centers are in the very middle of the cluster. In particular, you will see *empty* clusters very often, so **this initialization is usually your *worst* choice**.

If you insist, find the minimum and maximum on each axis, then draw random values from Uniform[min; max] each.

Comment: Does "if you insist" mean that that's exactly what we're *not* supposed to do?

Comment: Uniform data generation is one of the worst initializations for k-means. There is no reason to use it except to demonstrate how bad it is. But since you don't know the extend of your data, at least use the bounding box to sample from, not some fixed range that isn't even data based.

Answer (score 0):

Your current method is akin to the Forgy method of choosing initial centroids. Instead of looping and making random choices, you could use `random.sample` to chose *k* data-points. This is generally a good method. However your comment contradicts the question, in stating that the centroids must not be data-points.

An alternative method is to assign each data-point to an initial partition at random, (for example shuffle and then slice the data) and use the calculated centroids of the *k* randomly chosen partitions

```
random.shuffle(data)
random_partitions = [data[i::k] for i in range(k)]
centroids = [ "calculate centroid of partition()"  for partition in random_partitions]
```

This method tends to put the centroids near the middle of the data, which may be desirable.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Initialization_methods